# How Do I Find The Bounding Box For All Regions?

Tags: matlab

I'm using the [MNIST digit images](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/index.html) for a machine learning experiment, and I'm trying to center each image based on position, rather than the center of mass that they are centered on by default.

I'm using the regionprops class, BoundingBox method to extract the images. I create a B&W copy of the greyscale, use this to determine the BoundingBox properties (regionprops works only B&W images) and then apply that on the greyscale original to extract the precise image rectangle. This works fine on ~98% of the images.

The problem I have is that the other ~2% of images has some kind of noise or errant pixel in the upper left corner, and I end up extracting only that pixel, with the rest of the image discarded.

How can I incorporate all elements of the image into a single rectangle?

EDIT: Further research has made me realise that I can summarise and rephrase this question as "How do I find the bounding box for all regions?". I've tried adjusting a label matrix so that all regions are the same label, to no avail.

Comment: If it's a single pixel that messes things up, you may want to try `bwareaopen` to remove (too) small clusters before calculating the bounding box.

Comment: Another option is to use medfilt2 (median filter)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use an erosion mask with the same size of that noise to make it totally disappear  " using imerode followed by imdilate to inverse erosion ", or you can use median filter